Does the Arakan Army plan for Arakan/Rakhine State to declare independence?
The Arakan Army has been making great progress in conquering Arakan/Rakhine State.
If it succeeds, does it plan for Arakan to declare full independence? Or does it instead see Arakan as being part of a democratic Myanmar?
From a 2020 speech by the Commander-in-Chief Twan Mrat Naing:

The struggle for national liberation and the restoration of the Arakan’s sovereignty to the people of Arakan is our legitimate resistance in accordance with our natural and historic right. We are not asking the consent of the enemy; we are practically implementing our collective determination to throw off the shackles of the Burmese racism and colonialism in Arakan. This is our morale and faith in our own strength that we are going to attain the independence of Arakan whether the Burmese war criminals grant us or not; nothing can stop us.

But in a more recent 2024 BBC Radio interview, he instead states (as quoted by Eurasia Review):

We’ve never mentioned declaring independence before, and we don’t plan to in the future. However, after over 70 years of historical experience, we’ve learned that our goals are unattainable under the Military-led rule in Myanmar. Our vision is to shape Myanmar’s future through unity. Yet, if it’s clear we can’t achieve our aspirations, we must explore other options, shouldn’t we? ...
Our revolution cannot solely focus on Rakhine nationalism because the fate of all oppressed ethnic groups in Myanmar is inter-connected. ...
We must now prioritize the implementation of multi-ethnic liberation, equal rights, unity, and peace building guided by the Way of Rakhita. Some ethnic groups are not officially recognized in Myanmar’s ethnicities list. Therefore I believe that true progress can only be made when the concept of citizenship rights and responsibilities is clearly defined for all citizens, paving the way for systematic development and a brighter future ...
I believe that only when the rule of the military dictatorship ends, can we then secure a prosperous future for all Myanmar’s people and ensure lasting peace.


Sounds a bit like talking out of both sides of their mouth. To the loyalists, who need to be energized and will reward extreme ideas, talk about how you will achieve your maximalist goals any day now. To foreign moderates, who need to be placated and will reward stability, talk about human rights and ending dictatorship. Who knows which of those ideas is what they actually think?

@Obie2.0 On the other hand, there are four years between both statements. I have read recently a number of reports that say the military progress was underpinned, if not helped, by the multi-ethnic approach of the different insurgent groups. It is certainly worth to investigate more closely if Arakan Army has really changed their stance.
